# Pre-populating HTML/Jade from Express/node.js web app

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a web app that is built using Express for node.js. I'm using Jade template files for the HTML displays. In one of these displays I'd like to have the various fields pre-populated with data. The data is being stored in a mongodb session store, as well as in a separate collection in the db. I'd prefer to use the session data to pre-populate these fields in the HTML/Jade displays. How can I go about doing this (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the defaults to `res.locals` and then set the `input` elements `value` attribute in jade.

```
//node.js
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // Sorry I am unfamiliar with Mongo, not sure the syntax...
  mongo.get('defaults', function(err, body){
    res.locals.dName = body.defaultName;
    res.locals.dFoo = body.defaultFoo;
    res.render('myTemplate');
  });
});

//myTemplate.jade
!!!
html
  body
    form(action='/form', method='post')
      input#formName(name='name', value=locals.dName)
      input#formFoo(name='foo', value=locals.dFoo)
```

Comment: Why use `res.locals` if you can pass them to `res.render()` directly?

Comment: personal preference, mostly... also, sometimes I call `res.render` from a later middleware, and using `res.locals` is a handy way to save the values without having to pass them to the later middleware function some other way

Comment: I agree that `res.locals` is very useful to pass data along the middleware chain, just never saw anyone using it at the same location as where `res.render` was called :)

Comment: it also is a bit more readable in situations where the `local` variable is the result of some sort of computation instead of just assigning an existing thing. e.g `res.render('myTemplate', {dName:someFunction('foo', 'bar'), dFoo:someOtherFunction(JSON.stringify(baz, null,2))})`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using res.render() from the Express API to do this. I will credit Plato with the answer though because his also seems to be correct and he's a nice man for answering my question.

```
exports.viewProfile = function(req, res) {
    res.render('viewProfile', {username: req.session.user, firstname: req.session.firstname});
}
```