# Pre-populating Pug form from Express/Node.js web app

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a Node.js web app built with Express and am trying to populate a Jade template after querying MongoDB. I would like to populate the Jade template with these values.

Something I don't understand is why even when I comment out everything within the collection.find() function, and only have a 'res.render('editresource')' -- the view is not rendered. Am I not understanding something fundamental?

```
// From pug file (editresource.pug)
extends layout

block content
    h1 = title

    .main.container
        .row
            .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
                h1.display-4.m-b-2 Edit Resource

                // register form
                form(method='POST' action='/edit/editresource')
                    div.form-group
                        label(for='name') Name:
                        input#name.form-control(type='text', name='name', required='', value=locals.dName)

// From  Node.js/Express:
    router.get('/editresource/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var resource_collection = db.get('resources');

    var resourceId = req.params.id;

    resource_collection.find({'_id' : resourceId},{},function(e,docs){
        // res.render('editresource', {
        //  name : 'asdf'
        // });

        //res.locals.dName = docs[0].name;
        //res.render('editresource')

        res.render('editresource', { 'viewpost' : docs[0].name })

        //res.name = docs[0].name;
        //res.render('editresource', { name : docs[0].name });
    });
// attempting to call res.render('editresource') here does not work??
});

// All of this is fired by this function when a link is clicked
function editResource(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/edit/editresource/' + $(this).attr('rel')
    }).done(function( response ) {

        if (response.msg === '') {
        }
        else
            alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
    });
};
```

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386901/pre-populating-html-jade-from-express-node-js-web-app) but using res.locals does not work, nor does sending the whole object.

Comment: Is `docs[0].name` value string ?, if so , just use the `viewpost` for value :  `value=viewpost` in **jade**

Comment: Ah, yes. I edited the post for that change :) Unfortunately, still doesn't work -- though my view engine is currently pug.

Comment: is there any error message while rendering pug file ?

Comment: No errors -- though I'm still confused why the function will not render the view at all (does not navigate to new page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Parameters were being sent correctly but I didn't inject the html when the response was received on client-side. (e.g. $('#wrapper').html(response);)

Answer (score 0):

to use the variable sent to pug, you need to use the variable name properly.

```
div.form-group
    label(for='name') Name:
    input#name.form-control(type='text', name='name', required='', value=viewpost
```

Comment: Whoops, slight typo -- thanks! Unfortunately, this still doesn't properly populate the form.

Comment: Did you indent the code properly too? Its not indented correctly!

Comment: It is! I just took a snippet out of the whole file :) Just edited my post -- noticed that even trying to render the view is not working

Comment: you need to provide more information, what was the error? did you use routers for the pug engines properly 'app.set('view engine', 'pug');' . The code snippet you provided appears to be correct.

Comment: yes, view engine is set correctly. it seems like the problem is that the view is simply not rendered (if I comment out everything within my router.get() function and only make the call `res.render('editresource')`, the editresource.pug is not rendered

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to send `render()` method.

```
var renderData = { 
    dName = docs[0].name
};

res.render('editresource', renderData)
```

and change varaible name for **value** attribute of the input to `dName`

```
input#name.form-control(type='text', name='name', required='', value=dName)
```